# ng-bootstrap modal header and footer not displaying?

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 so I was able to launch modal window and rendered data from the component but I don't see header and footer that I have part of HTML I can not close the modal window. What is missing in below code?

modal.component.ts

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';

import {NgbModal, NgbActiveModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-modal-content',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
})
export class NgbdModalContent {
  @Input() name;

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {}
}
```

modal.component.html

```
<ng-template #theModal let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 *ngIf="type == 0" class="modal-title">Header</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" id="cancel-edit-btn" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="c('Close click')">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

home.component.ts

```
import {NgbModal,NgbActiveModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

export class HomeComponent implements OnChanges{

constructor(private detailService: DetailService,private ngbModal: NgbModal) {};

 onClick(evt){
     const modalRef = this.ngbModal.open(HomeComponent,{ size: 'lg', backdrop: 'static' });
   }

}
```

Comment: this.ngbModal.open( **NgbdModalContent**,{size:'lg',backdrop:'static'}); Your component.home open as modal your component NbgModalContent

Comment: how we will pass HomeComponent to modal then ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is an old question but here is an answer

I had the same issue and if you look close at the example provided they make use of the template reference variable ( #content ). To get it working with minor alteration you can import the additional elements required;

ViewChild and ElementRef

`import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';`

then under the closeResult variable add a reference to the templated variable

`closeResult: string;
@ViewChild('content') content: ElementRef;`

Then the header and footer will be shown as the content is rendered correctly with all the mark , otherwise content would just be the body and text you pass.

Cheers

Neil

Answer (score 0):

Using ngbModal you can, open a modal that belongs to your component (in this case your button and your  are in the same html, (it's the first example)

```
<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
...
</ng-template>

<button (click)="open(content)">Launch demo modal</button>
```

or open a component that was modal. In this case, the button is in one component, and the component modal is another
The modal component is like . See that there aren not "ng-template". And in the .ts it's necesary import NgbModal, NgbActiveModal to get function to close button

```
<div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Hi there!</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
    </div>
```

The component that open the modal must import NgbModal and put in the constructor to open the modal

Comment: ok i have changed ng-template to above suggested html and that change i made to modal.component.html and component that is calling modal i have ngbModal in constructor it opens the modal but still dont see `X` ,header and and footer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few classes and components that make up a Bootstrap 4 modal. You can't just leave out some of those classes and components and then hope to still get a working modal.

Use the following code snippet as a template. Your code needs to produce that HTML if you want a working modal. Don't leave out the necessary parts (divs & classes).

Click the "run code snippet" button below to see it working:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have copy html code exactly you have it and added all script and link index.html , still i dont see header and footer not sure whats happening

Comment: Do you see it when you click the "run code snippet" button here?

Comment: its showing here  not sure what is missing in my app

Comment: Well, in this case, you just aren't loading the correct Bootstrap 4 files. Make sure you copy those exact CDN links that I have here. Another possibility is that you need to clear the cache of your browser. One of those 2 options must be it.

Comment: no luck `@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
@import "~@angular-generic-table/column-settings/css/column-settings.css/";
@import "~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css";
@import "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc2/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css";` this what i have in style.css

Comment: Right. That means that you are loading css for Bootstrap 3 and that is, of course, incompatible with Bootstrap 4. Like **totally** incompatible. That's why I've been saying that you need to use the CDN links that I have in my code snippet.

Comment: Since you originally said, in your question, that you are using Bootstrap 4, I had actually assumed that you are using Bootstrap 4. But according to that comment of yours you seem to be using Bootstrap 3.

Comment: I mean, my assumption here is based on this line: `@import "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc2/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css";` You wouldn't need that for Bootstrap 4. That's totally a Bootstrap 3 thing.

Comment: that is for icons i dont think that is causing the issue i removed this line for now

Comment: Sure, that's for icons and wouldn't normally cause an issue. But that suggests that you aren't actually loading the required Bootstrap 4 files.

Comment: Look into this file: `"~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";` and see what's inside. I bet that's NOT Bootstrap 4 css that you have in there.

Comment: You might even have some Bootstrap 4 css in there but an **outdated** alpha or beta version of Bootstrap 4. You can't use those if you expect this thing to work.

Comment: They had breaking changes even up to the last beta version. So, if you have anything that's older than Bootstrap 4 beta-3, then that's definitely **no good**.